# Anonymous type 'is not valid' exception in Entity Framework code first OnModelCreating

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, anonymous-types

I am specifying my own database table names and schemas in the OnModelCreating() method in my strongly-typed DbContext as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyAssociativeClass>().ToTable("MYASSOCIATIVECLASS", schemaName: "MYSCHEMA");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyAssociativeClass>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ClassA.ID, ClassBID = x.ClassB.ID });
```

However, I get the following error:

> The properties expression 'x => new <>f__AnonymousType1`2(ID = x.MyClassA.ID, MyClassBID = x.MyClassB.ID)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New From { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

As you can see, both MyClassA and MyClassB have an ID property.  I am specifying a different name for MyClassB.ID in the anonymous type so there isn't a conflict with using the same property name twice.  BUt this still causes an issue.  Why won't it allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're class MyAssociativeClass will have to expose the foreign keys as properties, such that you could then do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyAssociativeClass>().ToTable("MYASSOCIATIVECLASS", schemaName: "MYSCHEMA");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyAssociativeClass>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ClassA_Id, ClassB_Id});
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, but that looks like the only way to get it to work.  Thanks.